# Type annotation for dict.items()

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-3.10

Sample code:

```py
def test() -> list[tuple[str, int]]:
    some_dict = {"some": 3, "another": 5}
    return some_dict.items()
```

For me it's quite obvious that it returns list of tuples: `[("some", 3), ("another": 5)]`.

But `dict.items()` actually returns `dict_items[("some", 3), ("another", 5)]` and above result can be only achieved when casting it to list.

I wanted to have type annotation for this case, but `list[tuple[str, int]]` isn't working (checked with MyPy version 0.961) and I can't find anywhere how to annotate `dict_items`.

How to annotate function like this (without casting it to list, and preserving information about return type, not just `Any`)?

Comment: `def test() -> ItemsView?`

Comment: did you mean you want to go through your function result and print it for example?

Comment: It **doesn't** return a list of tuples, whether or not you think that's obvious. What's important about the return value for your purposes? There's e.g. `collections.abc.ItemsView`, but maybe e.g. `Iterable` would be more appropriate.

Comment: It was just a sample code, ofc the main function was much more complicated but I wanted to process some data, add it to dict and then return dict.items(). 


Basicly I could omit the annotations, as they aren't necessary but for consistency reasons I wanted to annotate this function.  And yes I think that Iterable[tuple...] will be best solution. Thanks!

Comment: I voted to re-open because this question uses the generic parameters (stuff in `[]`s), while the supposed "duplicate" does not, and it's not easy to make that question do so.

Comment: @dfrankow I've gone ahead and updated the other question. It was already giving the dict parameters (the stuff in `[]`s) but answers didn't use that. They do now.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ItemsView`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ItemsView):

```
from typing import ItemsView


def test() -> ItemsView[str, int]:
    some_dict = {"some": 3, "another": 5}
    return some_dict.items()
```

**Output (mypy)**

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

In Python 3.9+ use instead:

```
from collections.abc import ItemsView
```

A more "general" solution would be to use [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable):

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def test() -> Iterable[tuple[str, int]]:
    some_dict = {"some": 3, "another": 5}
    return some_dict.items()
```

but on a personal note I prefer to stick with [Postel's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle):

> "be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept"

Comment: Note that's deprecated since Python 3.9, _per the link you posted_, as `collections.abc.ItemsView` supports the generic typing.

Comment: Sticking with Iterable soultion, as it's more readable for me at least.